# "create a unit test project" doesnt appear in visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller

When I create a new project. The "create a unit test project" isn't available to be pressed. Whats wrong?

I am using `visual studio 2010 ultimate`

Comment: Is the command missing entirely, or just grayed out? Did you install the unit testing functionality when you installed Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you know that you could write unit tests without "unit test project" take a look on NUnit (http://www.nunit.org/) and Mbunit (http://www.gallio.org/)

Comment: it is grayed out. I installed the program as usuall.. i did full install.. I can generate a unit test as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182526%28v=vs.80%29.aspx But i can see it when i create a new project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where this menu item is that you are trying to use, but we always add unit test projects by right-clicking on the solution, choosing `Add` then `New Project...`. Then we select the `Test` section under `Visual C#` and the `Test Project` item on the right-hand side.